# Create a table with sample 50k Entries/records in Postgresql database and calculate time

Tags: postgresql

I have created an [EC2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/28poz.png) on Amazon Linux 2 and have attached 4 EBS volumes to the instance and mounted them.
I have installed the Postgres source code on my Linux machine and connected to the server.

I want to know the script or code to create a sample table with 50k entries inside the database and check which EBS volume storage it uses out of those 4 so that I can figure out which EBS volume is taking less time to run a code (e.g. start date, end date, and time). [Database image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NpttK.png)

I tried to create a database and then create a table inside it.

I want to know the actual code to create a table with 50K sample entries.

Comment: You can use `generate_series(1,5e4,1)` to get 50k rows, `gen_random_uuid()` to get random texts and `random()` to get random numbers. [`create table public.test50k (emp_id serial primary key, emp_name text, empl_no integer); insert into public.test50k(emp_name,empl_no) select gen_random_uuid()::text, floor(random()*5e4)::int from generate_series(1,5e4,1);`](https://dbfiddle.uk/U8B79lM7) `SHOW data_directory;` to see where your db is saving the data. [Tablespaces](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtablespace.html) let it save elsewhere.

Comment: Once the database is created with table of 50--70k sample queries, how can I see which EBS volumes does it utilize the Space as I have attached 4 EBS volumes to an instance.

Comment: Connect to the database and run `SHOW data_directory;` the same way you ran your `create table` statements. It'll tell you the path where your data goes. Check out [`tablespaces`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtablespace.html) if you want some tables to go elsewhere, to some other paths on other volumes. On Linux you can also inspect the volume utilisation by running `df -hT`

Answer (score 1):

You can use

1. [`generate_series(1,5e4,1)`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-srf.html#FUNCTIONS-SRF-SERIES) to get 50k rows,
2. [`gen_random_uuid()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-uuid.html) to get random texts,
3. [`random()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-math.html#FUNCTIONS-MATH-RANDOM-TABLE) to get random numbers,
4. [`SHOW data_directory;`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-file-locations.html) to see where your db is saving the data,
5. [Tablespaces](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtablespace.html) to let it save elsewhere,
6. [`explain analyze verbose ...`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-explain.html) for simple, one-off tests,
7. [**`pg_bench`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgbench.html) for benchmarks.

```sql
create table public.test50k (
  emp_id serial primary key, 
  emp_name text, 
  empl_no integer); 

insert into public.test50k(emp_name,empl_no) 
select 
  gen_random_uuid()::text, 
  floor(random()*5e4)::int 
from generate_series(1,5e4,1);

explain analyze verbose 
select empl_no, count(*) from public.test50k group by 1;
```

[Online demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/DFUjlPWI)